# Redirect to specific path in Angular after EXTERNAL login

Tags: angular

Starter code (fake app): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n2f8we?file=src/app/before-login.component.ts

**I am trying to redirect my app to a route/URL after authorizing my app with an external API.**

The real app starts at a URL like https://localhost:44444/aaa123-o3461 (let's call this the **original URL**). The stuff after the last '/' is the **GUID** which is like a unique ID for one of the "workspaces" that belong to the user.

That URL takes the user to the Authorize page (please see the linked Stackblitz app). The Authorize button is in the `BeforeLogin` component, and the page to be redirected to is the `AfterLogin` component. (I have routes set up incorrectly in the AppRouting module. Not sure how to do it correctly for the real app at this point )

The Authorize button takes the user to an external Microsoft login page by doing `window.location.href = url`. After logging in successfully, the user is automatically redirected to a URL that looks like https://localhost:44444/#access_token=myAccessToken_xyz123abc&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=5000.

**What I want:** I need to grab ☝️those parameter values (like the `access_token` and `expires_in`) from that **redirect URL**, store them in the session storage (so the user doesn't have to re-authorize until the expiration time), and then redirect to the `AfterLogin` page immediately. The URL in the address bar needs to be the original URL, i.e., https://localhost:44444/aaa123-o3461 in the AfterLogin page.

**What I have tried:** At the moment, I can save the access token and expiration date to the session storage. To redirect to the original URL, I save it in the local storage in the Authorize button's `onClick()`, and load it back if/when the URL contains the string "https://localhost:44444/#access_token=". However, the redirect URL loads and shows an error message before redirecting to the `AfterLogin` page in my real app, which makes for a poor user experience. I want to make it so the user doesn't even notice the access token URL. Also, loading and storing the original URL in the localStorage seems highly error-prone. I am also not sure how to do the routing correctly (please see the app-routing module).

**Notes:**

- The real app runs on https://localhost:44444/ locally on my machine, and has it's own URLs in dev, prod, stage and QA environments. The root URL (i.e., localhost:44444/), just shows a blank page and goes nowhere. To get to the Authorize page, there needs to be a GUID attached, for example: https://localhost:44444/aaa123-o3461-762a3-po34-u4uf83.
- In the real app, the USER has to login with internal credentials, which then redirects the user to a URL with a GUID like https://company.xyz-internal.us-east.com/this-is-a-guid-abc123-456def-ijk789 to get to the Authorize button page. I need the user to be taken to the AfterLogin page without needing to do the internal login again (which already happens automatically).

Answer (score 2):

You are confused because you want two different behaviors for the same route.
I suggest to split it into separate routs.
Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-axn84e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexternal-login.component.ts

When user tries to access https://localhost:44444/aaa123-o3461 (**AfterLogin**), check with guard does he have access or not. If yes - allow, if not - save guid and redirect to the login page. For example - https://localhost:44444/login.

On login page, auth user in whatever way you want. In your case redirect to microsoft oauth, also you need to configure it to redirect you after successful login to separate route, for example https://localhost:44444/external?access_token=bla_bla_bla.

There you save your credentials and redirect user back to guid route.
https://localhost:44444/aaa123-o3461

Also you can pass guid as additional parameter to microsoft auth string like -
https://login.microsoftonline.com/e843523-3452-123s-6453-278356s53dd53/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id=wef6734-o346-7623-po34-u4uf834jdf8&state=**your_guid**
so it will be returned back and you don't need to restore it from localStore

Comment: Thanks. This is all exactly what I needed, especially the last bit.

Comment: The route matcher does not seem to be working. I placed a breakpoint in `guidRouteMatcher()` but it looks like we are never even calling the method.

Comment: It's strange, if I add console.log inside guidRouteMatcher(), I see logs in console